# Google settings account information showing error

Tags: google-settings

I am using Jio LYF LS4503 Mobile. It is re unrooted via kingroot App. Now the problem is that in Google settings Account information showing error. It is loading after a few seconds it shows error like screenshot.

[image]

I am using Jio 4G network. It works fine and i also tried using wifi but every time error appears.
What should i do to fix that?

Comment: I can manage account from chrome browser, but in  Google settings , it shows error.